# Bootstrap Validator não valida select com dados php

Tags: php, validação, bootstrap

Bom eu tenho em meu `form` de cadastro um campo `select` que é populado com dados vindo do banco de dados, porém com o uso do `Bootstrap Validator`, ele não valida corretamente, agora se eu tirar o código `PHP` ele valida corretamente.
O que pode ser isso.

Abaixo esta o meu campo select:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="AgentePG" class=" control-label">PG</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="AgentePG" name="pg" data-bv-notempty data-bv-notempty-message="The country is required">
    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
    <?php
      $sql = DB::getInstance();
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM pg";
      $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $busca = $stmt->fetchAll();
          foreach ($busca as $linha) {
             echo '<option value=' . $linha->id . '>' . $linha->pg . </option>';
          }
      ?>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez seja erro de sintaxe nessas aspas. Copie essa linha e substitua.

```
echo '<option value="' . $linha->id . '">' . $linha->pg . '</option>';
```